# How do you create a fractal cube-map?

Tags: opengl, java, cubemap

I want to create a map similar to how Mincraft and other related games do. I just haven't the faintest clue on how to do so. Can anyone point me to a decent tutorial or give me a decent run through? I program in java and use openGL.

Comment: Could you give a description of what a fractal cube-map is? I haven't heard that term before and it doesn't seem to be easily found on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[Voxel heightmap terrain editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12277/voxel-heightmap-terrain-editor/12282#12282)

The article I mention in that answer is pretty good and talks about creating maps exactly like Minecraft. Using that article as a starter I was able to create maps like [this](http://byte56screens.tumblr.com/post/7373767285/the-maps-are-almost-looking-playable-at-least-for) for my game.