# 3D Procedural Planet Generation - Resource

Tags: xna, c#, procedural-generation, procedural

I don't know if the question fits on this site (if it doesn't I'll gladly accept any invitation to move it elsewhere), anyhow, I have found this [Really great resource](http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/sloup/pages/theses/LindaOndrej2007.pdf) on [3D Procedural Planet generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24126/3d-procedural-planet-generation) and am nearly finished reading it, some things I can grasp quite well, other parts, not a all. However the thesis makes references to its "Enclosed CD" which contains source code for the project that is demonstrated throughout the document, the problem is there is no cd rom (obliviously) and there are no links to an online version of the source code.

I would be highly grateful if I could obtain a copy of it,  any ideas, or links to similar tutorials/articles on the topic of 3D Procedural Planet generation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this question is a fit for this site, but have you considered emailing the professor of this student? His email address is listed on the site: http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/sloup/

Comment: If you ask a new question about 3D Procedural Planet generation, you'd probably get some answers. As it is, nobody will be able to answer your question, therefore I have flagged this question as too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider contacting the author directly. Here is his LinkedIn profile: http://www.linkedin.com/pub/ondrej-linda/10/548/566 . His thesis is mentioned at the bottom of the profile page.

You could try contacting him via LinkedIn, or use the info on the page to contact him somewhere else (looks like he's at the University of Idaho now).

Good luck.